# how to make the user\password required for Base postgresql connection

Tags: postgresql, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I'm building an entry form frontend to postgresql using libreoffice 4.0
the first time i open it it will ask me for user name and password,
if they were correct it won't ask for it again

the problem is it won't ask for it again even if i close the Base file and reopened it

all my users management is on postgresql side,

so i need Base to ask for password each time i close and reopen it

maybe there's a way to use macros to clear the cache of the password,
and add a button called "logout" which will clear the password cache, so for the next connection Base will ask for the user/password
but i couldn't find the API for it

thanks a lot,
Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way,

when setting the connection parameters don't add a user and don't test the connection,
just check the "password required" save and close,
when you reopen the database and try to open a form it will prompt for username and password,

and i made sure that the type of connection in my 'pg_hba.conf' is 'md5' not 'peer'